# Transform Scale of Columns into a range from 1 to 10

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a set of new columns that would be derived from an existing columns in a dataframe using a function.  Here is sample code that produces errors and I wonder if there a better more efficient way to accomplish it than the loop

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='M')
long_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4),index=dates, columns=['Colorado', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Ohio'])
mylist=['Colorado', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Ohio']

def trnsfrm_1_10 (a, b):
    b = (a-np.min(a))/(np.max(a)-np.min(a))*9+1
    return b

for a in mylist:   
    b=a+"_T"
    long_df[b] = long_df.apply(lambda row: trnsfrm_1_10(row[a], row[b]), axis=1)
```

To clarify above question, here is example of DataFrame that has input columns (Colorado, Texas, New York) and output variables (T_Colorado, T_Texas, T_New York).  Let's assume that if for each input variable, below are minimum and maximum of each column then by applying equation: b = (a-min)/(max-min)*9+1 to each column, the output variables are T_Colorado T_Texas     T_New York.  I had to simulate this process in excel based on just 5 rows, but it would be great to compute minimum and maximum as part of the function because I would have a lot more rows in the real data.  I am relatively new to Python and Pandas and I really appreciate your help.

These are example min and max

```
    Colorado    Texas   New York
min   0.03     -1.26    -1.04           
max   1.17      0.37     0.86
```

This is example of a DataFrame

```
Index     Colorado  Texas   New York T_Colorado T_Texas  T_New York
1/31/2000   0.03     0.37    0.09      1.00      10.00     6.35
2/29/2000   0.4      0.26   -1.04      3.92       9.39     1.00
3/31/2000   0.35    -0.06   -0.75      3.53       7.63     2.37
4/30/2000   1.17    -1.26   -0.61     10.00       1.00     3.04
5/31/2000   0.46    -0.79    0.86      4.39       3.60     10.00
```

Comment: Can you post a small example with expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the error is that when you define `trnsfrm_1_10`, `b` is a parameter while actually it's only your output. It should not be a parameter, especially as it's the value in the new column you want to create during the loop `for`. so the code would be more something like:

```
def trnsfrm_1_10 (a):
    b = (a-np.min(a))/(np.max(a)-np.min(a))*9+1
    return b

for a in mylist:   
    b=a+"_T"
    long_df[b] = long_df.apply(lambda row: trnsfrm_1_10(row[a]), axis=1)
```

The other thing is that you calculate `np.min(a)` in `trnsfrm_1_10` which actually will be equal to `a` (same with `max`) because you `apply` row wise so `a` is the unique value in the row and column you are in. I assume what you mean would be more `np.min(long_df['a'])` which can also be written `long_df[a].min()`

If I understand well, what you try to perform is actually:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='M')
long_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4),index=dates, 
                       columns=['Colorado', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Ohio'])
mylist=['Colorado', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Ohio']

for a in mylist:
    long_df[a+"_T"] = (long_df[a]-long_df[a].min())/(long_df[a].max()-long_df[a].min())*9+1
```

giving then:

```
long_df.head()
Out[29]: 
            Colorado     Texas  New York      Ohio  Colorado_T   Texas_T  \
2000-01-31 -0.762666  1.413276  0.857333  0.648960    3.192754  7.768111   
2000-02-29  0.148023  0.304971  1.954966  0.656787    4.676018  6.082177   
2000-03-31  0.531195  1.283100  0.070963  1.098968    5.300102  7.570091   
2000-04-30 -0.385679  0.425382  1.330285  0.496238    3.806763  6.265344   
2000-05-31 -0.047057 -0.362419 -2.276546  0.297990    4.358285  5.066955   

            New York_T    Ohio_T  
2000-01-31    6.390972  5.659870  
2000-02-29    8.242445  5.676254  
2000-03-31    5.064533  6.601876  
2000-04-30    7.188740  5.340175  
2000-05-31    1.104787  4.925180
```

where all the value in the colum with `_T` are calculated from the corresponding column.

Ultimately to not use a `for` loop over the column, you can do:

```
long_df_T =(((long_df -long_df.min(axis=0))/(long_df.max(axis=0) -long_df.min(axis=0))*9 +1)
             .add_suffix('_T'))
```

to create a dataframe with all the columns with `_T` at once. Then few option are available to add them in `long_df`, one way is with `join`:

```
long_df = long_df.join(long_df_T)
```

Comment: Very thorough explanation :)

Comment: Thank you very much, all solutions work great, but for some reason the solutions without looping are adding two sets of transformed columns, one with _T and another set with _TT.  Both sets are correct and identical, it is just two of them.

Comment: @Nora the second method should be used on the original `long_df`, not the one if you already used the method with the loop `for`. Otherwise, the columns created with the loop `for` are again considered, so you get the other set `_T_T` columns from these columns :)

Comment: @Nora I mean when you create `long_df_T` it should be on the original `long_df`. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense and thank you so much!  The solutions work great and very optimal.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you should take advantage of broadcasting

```
long_df2= (long_df - long_df.min())/(long_df.max() - long_df.min()) * 9 + 1
```

Then `concat`

```
pd.concat([long_df, long_df2.add_suffix('_T')], 1)
```